# How to convert 2011 -Q4 to 12-31-2011 in oracle sql?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to convert `2011 -Q4` to `12-31-2011` in Oracle sql?

Comment: Maybe with a `CASE WHEN`? Cf. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/expressions004.htm

Comment: you could use a substr function to isolate Q4 and use a decode call to replace it ..

Comment: If your string will be in a consistent format, you could always use a reference table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This expression should work to transform the value into the date:

```
select add_months(to_date(substr(yq, 1, 4)||'-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD'), substr(yq, -1, 1) * 3) - interval '1' day
from (select '2011-Q4' as yq from dual) x
```

If you want the date as a particular string format, then use `to_char()`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to convert a lot of quarter strings, you can create a ref table to JOIN to.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e01c1/4)

**Create the test data**:

```
CREATE TABLE src (qtrDate varchar(20));

INSERT INTO src (qtrDate)
SELECT '2011 -Q4' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '2010 -Q3' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '2011 -Q1' FROM dual UNION ALL
SELECT '2012 -Q1' FROM dual
;
```

**Create the reference table and data**:

```
CREATE TABLE ref_quarters ( qtrString varchar(20), qtrEnd date, qtrBegin date ) ;
INSERT INTO ref_quarters ( qtrString, qtrEnd, qtrBegin )
SELECT to_char( dt, 'yyyy -"Q"q' )
  , dt
  , trunc(add_months(dt,-2),'mm')
FROM (
  SELECT add_months( '31-DEC-2009', rownum*3) dt
  FROM all_objects
  WHERE rownum <= 20 /* 20 Quarters since 2010 Q1 */
)
```

*NOTE: Update the dates and the rownum in the inner query to change when the quarter counting should start and how many quarters you want. You can also use this value to change the definition of your quarters as long as part of Q1 falls in JAN and the quarter starts on the first of the month (ie Q1 starts on 30 NOV instead of 1 JAN).*

**Now just join the two**:

```
SELECT qtrString AS originalStrin
  , TO_CHAR(qtrEnd,'MM/DD/YYYY') AS convertedString
FROM src
LEFT OUTER JOIN ref_quarters ON src.qtrDate = ref_quarters.qtrString
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7e01c1/4/0)**:

```
| ORIGINALSTRIN | CONVERTEDSTRING |
|---------------|-----------------|
|      2010 -Q3 |      09/30/2010 |
|      2011 -Q1 |      03/31/2011 |
|      2011 -Q4 |      12/31/2011 |
|      2012 -Q1 |      03/31/2012 |
```

This can also give you the benefit of making your date strings an actual date object, and you can also add various other data points to the ref table.